# How I can create a directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How I can make a new Folder, after I checked if this directory doesn't exists already, something like this :

```
; Create the temp dir with fix path name!
  !define TMPDIR "C:\temp"
  IfFileExists ${TMPDIR}\*.* +2
    CreateDirectory ${TMPDIR}
```

Comment: Eh, `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\temp");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
  String directoryToCreate = @"C:\temp";

  if (!Directory.Exists(directoryToCreate))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToCreate);
```

Comment: You forgot the `!` in your `if` statement

Comment: Or just call `CreateDirectory`; it wont throw if the path already exists

Comment: @AlexK. I did not know that. Any time I've ever seen `CreateDirectory` used it's always been prefaced by a check. Is there a reason for that, if `CreateDirectory` won't blow up if it already exists?

Comment: Its designed to create all parts of a path that does not exist, so falling over on the first one would mean it could not do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\temp"))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\temp")
```

Comment: don't forget to escape those slashes

Comment: You can just call `CreateDirectory`, no need to check if it exists first. `CreateDirectory` doesn't do anything if the directory already exists.